# regexp match in pandas

Tags: python, regex, pandas

In want to execute a regexp match on a dataframe column in order to modify the content of the column.
For example, given this dataframe:

import pandas as pd

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['abra'], ['charmender'], ['goku']],
     columns=['Name'])
print(df.head())
```

I want to execute the following regex match:

```
CASE 
   WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Landing Page,'abra') THEN "kadabra" 

   WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Landing Page,'charmender') THEN "charmaleon" 

ELSE "Unknown" END
```

My solution is the following:

```
df.loc[df['Name'].str.contains("abra", na=False), 'Name'] = "kadabra"
df.loc[df['Name'].str.contains("charmender", na=False), 'Name'] = "charmeleon"
df.head()
```

It works but I do not know if there is a better way of doing it.

Moreover, I have to rewrite all the regex cases line by line in Python. Is there a way to execute the regex directly in Pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for `map`:

```
df['Name'] = df['Name'].map({'abra':'kadabra','charmender':'charmeleon'})
```

Output:

```
         Name
0     kadabra
1  charmeleon
2         NaN
```

---

**Update**: For partial matches:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['this abra'], ['charmender'], ['goku']],
     columns=['Name'])


replaces = {'abra':'kadabra','charmender':'charmeleon'}
df['Name'] = df['Name'].str.extract(fr"\b({'|'.join(replaces.keys())})\b")[0].map(replaces)
```

And you get the same output (with different dataframe)

Comment: yes, this is indeed another option. But I have anyway to "translate" the regex into a mapping

Comment: however, the str.contains method works better in my case because I need it to work also with partial matches